# Aapt unknown command '--output-text-symbols'

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I've just upgraded my Android environment to:

- macOS 10.13.5
- Andorid Studio 3.1.4
- gradle 4.6
- gradle plugin 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
- Android SDK 28
- Build tool 28.0.2

However, when I was going to build my project it always fails at the task `processXXXDebugResources` with such error:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 111853366) : No Delegate set : lost message:error: unknown command '--output-text-symbols'.
AAPT err(Facade for 111853366) : No Delegate set : lost message:Error
Failed to execute aapt
```

I have no idea where does the `--output-text-symbols` come from. It looks like the `--output-text-symbols` was a parameter for the program `aapt` but the latest gradle plugin uses another new `aapt2`.

The `android.enableAapt2=false` could make this issue disappear but a warning tells this option will be deprecated.

```
The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
```

Comment: --output-text-symbols
    Generates a text file containing the resource symbols of the R class in the specified folder.

Comment: Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988596/3974530

Comment: @InsaneCat I checked this option but as I mentioned it will be deprecated so I'm looking for a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In my build.gradle there was an `aaptOptions` with a zero length string parameter:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress ""  // <- zero length string
}
```

It used to work on the 2.x gradle plugin, but failed on the latest 3.x version. It looks like the new plugin provided incorrect arguments for `aapt` command.

My suspicion:

In the old version the arguments might be:

```
aapt -0 '' --output-text-symbols
        ^
this is the zero-length string from aaptOptions in bulid.gradle
```

But in the latest version this becomes to:

```
aapt -0 --output-text-symbols
        ^
something is missing
```

And then I tried to use a one char length space string:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress " "  // <- one char length space string
}
```

I guess the arguments now become to:

```
aapt -0 ' ' --output-text-symbols
         ^
  the space comes back
```

Then it fix the problem for me.

Comment: You are exactly right, we've encountered this before and the support for this is added in 3.2 canaries. Good job figuring this out by yourself!